# SVN how to merge similar file trees (merge two branches)

Tags: svn, merge, branch

what I want to do:

```
branch A -> part of the project, e.g:
/project/module/a
/project/module/a/file-1

branch B -> part of the project, e.g:
/project/module/b
/project/module/b/file-2

deployment branch -> merge of A and B
/project/module/a
/project/module/a/file-1
/project/module/b
/project/module/b/file-2
```

one would think this is possible yet i can't get it to work...

what happens is this:

I merge A into deployment without a problem, but when i try to merge B afterwards I get a tree conflict, from what i read so far svn thinks A "deleted" B and vice versa... so thats the conflict? is svn only capable of merging basically the same tree?

if i understood the concept of branches right then one is supposed to create them by copying the trunk thus copying the whole source... so putting modules (parts of the whole source/project) into a branch is not a good idea or even impossible?

what i need is just adding stuff not trying to find the intersection of A and B because that in fact would not work :/

_***EDIT*_**

merging from /project/module/a and /project/module/b does not help since a module splits into more folders, e.g:

```
A:    
/project/module/stuff/a
/project/module/things/a    
B:    
/project/module/stuff/b
/project/module/things/b
```

so what one wants, is to at least merge from module otherwise one would have to merge each subfolder individually which contradicts the whole automagical merging ... ?

btw this structure is not my choice i have to work with it

Answer (score 0):

merge starting from the module, not from the base of the tree:
so for module a, start your merge from /project/module/a
and for module b, start your merge from /project/module/b

Comment: i edited my question... what you suggest i already tried and it sort of works but leaves it to me to check if i merged everything

Answer (score 0):

If modules haven't common parents,  it can produce strange results

From other side svn merge accept URLs as both parameters

Can you show real full commands, used in task? I can't see problems from my mind

```
svn merge URLBranchA URLBranchB .
```

And really with described tree youmust use svn;external and forget merging at all